# How can I get US State from GeoIP2?

Tags: php, location, geoip, maxmind

Is there any way, how to get US state abbr. (CA, VI, ..) from IP?

The library return me only metro code and postal code, is there any lookup table to state convertor? Or how do you extract the state?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to look in the `subdivisions` section, which is the generic container for States, Provinces, etc. depending on the country.

If you're using the web API, [here are those docs](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/web-services/#subdivisions), and this is the relevant chunk from their output example:

```
"subdivisions":  [
    {
        "confidence":  50,
        "geoname_id":  5332921,
        "iso_code":    "CA",
        "names":  {
            "de":    "Kalifornien",
            "en":    "California",
            "es":    "California",
            "fr":    "Californie",
            "ja":    "カリフォルニア",
            "ru":    "Калифорния",
            "zh-CN": "加州"
        }
    }
]
```

The [PHP client](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php#city-example) using a downloaded IP DB has `mostSpecificSubdivision`:

```
print($record->mostSpecificSubdivision->name . "\n"); // 'Minnesota'
print($record->mostSpecificSubdivision->isoCode . "\n"); // 'MN'
```

Comment: Thank you, accepted as answer, the subdivisions are the best.